# Create a JS Pop-Up to a link with a Data from Database

Tags: javascript, php, href

I have here my href link being echoed:

```
echo "<td><a href='../php/borrowersname.php?acc_number=".$row['acc_number']."'>".$row['title']."</a></td>";
```

And I have here a sample on how to create a Pop-Up:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('some.html', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');">Test</a>
```

How to combine this to my `href link` above being echoed with the `"javascript ... ..."` enclosed by `("" && '')`?

Thanks for another new learning.

Comment: I've tried but other lines enclosed with `""` does not function :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the `""`

```
<?php
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:window.open('../php/borrowersname.php?acc_number=".$row['acc_n‌​umber']."', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');\">Test</a>";
?>
```

In the 'borrowersname.php' page, you can get the value of 'acc_number' like this:

```
<?php
    $value = $_GET['acc_number'];
    //do something with $value;
?>
```

Comment: Okay. Works fine but getting the value from this borrowersname.php?acc_number=".$row['acc_n‌​umber'] does not work anymore.  :(

Comment: You mean that on the borrowersname.php page you can't get the value of acc_number?

Comment: Yes. But when not combined, it works. When JS now is there, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that $row['acc_n‌​umber'] contains the desired value?

Comment: Yes. I have the right query on selecting it. It works without JS. But what I want to have is a pop-up window. And then I applied yours. Good that the Pop-Up window works. But the get value does not.